# Can Spring MVC support a custom editor when binding comma separated strings to a List<String>?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC form where a comma separated list of Strings (from a multi select) is bound to a `List<String>` in my form object.

I would like to register a custom editor to perform some additional sanitisation on each String within the list.

I tried overriding the editor for the field name with my own `CustomCollectionEditor` but this seems to break each of the elements in the comma separated string being bound to a separate index in the `List<String>`. I only see the complete comma separated list when overriding `convertElement`.

Is is possible to register a custom editor that can process each String element of the List individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversion of the comma separated String to `List<String>` is handled by [org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToCollectionConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/support/StringToCollectionConverter.java).

To support my custom sanitisation I implemented the following:

1. Created an annotation to annotate the fields to be sanitised.
2. Implemented a custom [org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConditionalGenericConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/ConditionalGenericConverter.java) to handle converting and sanitising annotated `String` and `List<String>` fields. This was a converter where the `sourceType` was `String` and the `targetType` was either `String` or `List<String>`.
3. Registered my custom converter in the Spring MVC configuration.

Comment: Hi @Mark, thanks for the suggestion. Can you please provide an example of the conditional generic converter that you are talking about?